How can I simulate asynchronous LINQ queries with conditional logic in xUnit?
I'm writing unit tests for a service, and I need to simulate a more complex LINQ query that includes conditional logic and asynchronous methods, such as FirstOrDefaultAsync().
The query involves several chained methods like filtering, ordering, and selection:
var result = await _products
    .Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId)
    .Where(x => x.Stock > 0)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Price)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

I want to simulate the behavior of the entire query, including the Where(), OrderBy(), and FirstOrDefaultAsync() methods, and provide custom results for testing different scenarios.
I'm using Moq to simulate the data layer, but I'm unsure how to simulate the entire query chain and make it asynchronous.

As mentioned while this was in Staging Ground: I'd avoid mocks for this, and instead use fakes. Use an in-memory collection of products, and let that handle the querying for you. You can check that your code is doing the right thing by using appropriate data sets (e.g. including out-of-stock products, ones in different categories etc).

Those aren't asynchronous LINQ queries. They're asynchronous Entity Framework queries that translate LINQ into SQL and then execute the ADO.NET query asynchronously. Mocking will test nothing but the mocking code. If you want to test asynchronous execution use SQLite in in-memory mode at least

What are you trying to test anyway? The results? The generated SQL? What is _products?

As Jon Skeet suggests, Moq isn't suited for this kind of testing. I can't tell exactly what's happened in the staging ground alluded to (or, I don't know how to view that discussion), so I'll try to elaborate.
Functions like Where, OrderBy, and FirstOrDefaultAsync are extension methods, so can't be swapped out by a Test Double. There are plenty questions here on Stack Overflow about using Moq to test extension methods, and the answer is invariably: You can't. Here's one: How do I use Moq to mock an extension method?
What you may try to do is to figure out how an extension method like Where is implemented on top of IEnumerable<T> or IQueryable<T>, but that's going to make your test complicated and fragile. The test will be testing the implementation details of Where, OrderBy, etc. Furthermore, this will be difficult to do without access to the source code of each extension method, and I'm not sure that FirstOrDefaultAsync is open source.
Additionally, if you use interaction-based testing you'll have a Fragile Test on your hands. The test would have too narrow a view of what would constitute an expected interaction.
Consider the code example from the OP:
var result = await _products
    .Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId)
    .Where(x => x.Stock > 0)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Price)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Even if you assume that you can write enough Moq setups to simulate this interaction, the test would expect that Where is called exactly with those two predicates.
What would happen if another programmer comes by and decides to fuse the two predicates together (which would be an appropriate optimization to perform)?
var result = await _products
    .Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId && x.Stock > 0)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Price)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

This is an entirely equivalent query which should result in exactly the same answer, but it would break an interaction-based test.
Or, assuming that Stock is an integer, someone might decide to change the query to this:
var result = await _products
    .Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId)
    .Where(x => x.Stock >= 1)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Price)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Again, this minute refactoring shouldn't change the observable behaviour of the system, but it will break interaction-based tests.
Finally, you can combine the above two edits to this:
var result = await _products
    .Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId && x.Stock >= 1)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Price)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Again, this doesn't change the behaviour of the query, but breaks interaction-based tests.
The more complex the query is, the more likely it is that there's more than one way you can write it, and the more prone to changes it will be.
For that reason, I recommend that you favour state-based tests over interaction-based tests. Or, as Jon Skeet wrote, use a Fake Object instead.
